# BillDesk Payment Gateway Integration with Java

Tags: spring, payment-gateway

I am using billdesk payment gateway with spring and angularjs.The problem i am facing is everything works perfectly fine if i give localhost as url.But if i give server address nothing is working.I am getting the response from billdesk as parameter msg.Therefore from spring class i am calling like this

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/getDonationDetails",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})


    public String getDonationDetails(@RequestParam String msg) 
    {
    logger.info("msg:"+msg);
    //remaining code
    }
```

But in server address it is displaying error as Required String parameter 'msg' is not present.But for localhost everything is working.Can anyone tell why it is not able to run on server address?

Answer (score 0):

Try using request parameter map instead of plain msg parameter and check if it works.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getDonationDetails",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})


    public String getDonationDetails(@RequestParam Map<String, String> reqParamMap) 
    {
    logger.info("msg:" + reqParamMap.get("msg"));
    //remaining code
    }
```